# Angular: Load data from two components to a single component one at a time

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I'm creating a news portal and I have a category component and a navbar component. Both of these components contain categories. My aim is to load the news for a particular category like sports, entertainment.. etc. What I tried is that both my category component and navbar component points to the same news component to load the news for a particular category.

The issue is that I'm not able to do so because when I tried to select a category from the navigation menu it doesnt work and when i try from the category component it sometimes work and sometime doesnt't

I want to load the categories from the navigation menu irrespective on what page it is and also it shouldn't interfere with the category component

Both the category component and navbar components points to the same news component

Can anyone please help me in this issue.

I have pasted on the codes from my project

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarService } from '../navbar.service';
import * as $ from "jquery";
import { CategoryService } from '../category.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  dropDownCategories:any

  constructor(public nav: NavbarService, private categories: CategoryService, private router: Router) { 
  }

  //to transfer data to navabr service which goes to the news page
  getTitle(title){
    localStorage.setItem('navCategorySelected',title)
    location.reload()
    this.router.navigate(['/news'])
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //to load categories in drop down list
    this.categories.getCategories().subscribe(res=>{
      this.dropDownCategories=res
      this.dropDownCategories=this.dropDownCategories.result
    })

    //for the drop down animation
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.navbar-light .dmenu').hover(function () {
          $(this).find('.sm-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
      }, function () {
          $(this).find('.sm-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(105)
      });
  });

  }  

}
```

category.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../category.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarService } from '../navbar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category.component.css']
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  holdCategoryData: any

  isShow: boolean;// for scroll-up
  topPosToStartShowing = 100;//for scroll-up

  constructor(private catergoryService: CategoryService,private router: Router, public nav:NavbarService) {

    this.catergoryService.getCategories().subscribe(catlog => {
      this.holdCategoryData = catlog
      this.holdCategoryData = this.holdCategoryData.result
      console.log('======Category Output is ========', catlog, '====== type of ======', typeof catlog)
    })

  }


  //scroll code begins here
  @HostListener('window:scroll')
  checkScroll() {

    // window의 scroll top
    // Both window.pageYOffset and document.documentElement.scrollTop returns the same result in all the cases. window.pageYOffset is not supported below IE 9.

    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

    if (scrollPosition >= this.topPosToStartShowing) {
      this.isShow = true;
    } else {
      this.isShow = false;
    }
  }

  // TODO: Cross browsing
  gotoTop() {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }

  //gets the category name and goes to news page
  getTitle(title) {
    console.log("====Page title is =====", title)
    localStorage.setItem('categorySelected',title)
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/news')
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nav.show()//loads navbar

  }

}
```

news.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarService } from '../navbar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.css']
})
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {
  arr=[]

  holdNews:any
  constructor(private allNews:NewsService, private router: Router, public nav:NavbarService) {

    //to get news when category is clicked
    this.allNews.getNews().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('=========News Component output==========', res)
      this.holdNews=res
      this.holdNews=this.holdNews.result
      this.allNews.holdnews=this.holdNews
    })

    //to get news when navigation elements are clicked
    this.nav.getNews().subscribe(nres=>{
      console.log('=========Nav Component output==========', nres)
      this.holdNews=nres
      this.holdNews=this.holdNews.result
    })
  }

  readMore(title, newsimg,fulldescp){
    localStorage.setItem('det_title',title)
    localStorage.setItem('det_img',newsimg)
    localStorage.setItem('det_fulldescp',fulldescp)
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/detailednews')
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nav.show()

  }

}
```

news.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {
  holdnews:any

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getNews(){
    let holdHeader=localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    console.log('===Access token is ====',holdHeader)
    let queryParams={start:"0",limit:"10", category:localStorage.getItem('categorySelected')}
    let header = new HttpHeaders({'accesstoken':holdHeader})
    let options = { headers: header }

    return this.http.post<any>('...link...',queryParams,options)
  }

}
```

navbar.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavbarService {
  visible: boolean;

  constructor(public http : HttpClient) { this.visible = false; }

  hide() { this.visible = false; }

  show() { this.visible = true; }

  toggle() { this.visible = !this.visible; }

  //to get news when the drop down elements are clicked
  getNews(){
    let holdHeader=localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    console.log('===Access token is ====',holdHeader)
    let queryParams={start:"0",limit:"10", category:localStorage.getItem('navCategorySelected')}
    let header = new HttpHeaders({'accesstoken':holdHeader})
    let options = { headers: header }
    return this.http.post<any>('...link...',queryParams,options)
  }

}
```

Comment: Can u please share stackblitz URL for this code?

Comment: @prathameshk73 I don't have this code on stackblitz kinda new to this so dont know much about angular

Comment: You can commit your project in github and access it like this 

stackblitz.com/github/{GH_USERNAME}/{REPO_NAME}  

Refer below documentation 

https://stackblitz.com/docs#import-from-github

Comment: @PratikGhagare I think you should read about Input and Output with parent-child component in angular first and then observable (2nd solution). Also my concern is why are using jquery here. you are destroying whole purpose of angular by using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find all the answers to your question in this section of the Angular documentation : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Either use component parent/child relationship or a service to share information between your components.